# stuck and keep getting this error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webHomePage'

Tags: python, django, debugging, error-handling, module

Below are my Url Patterns

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls.conf import path

from.import index


urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('',index.webhomepage,name='HomePage'),
       path('PublicSchools',index.webpublicschoolspage,name='PublicSchools'),
       path('PrivateSchools',index.webprivateschoolspage,name='PrivateSchools'),
]
```

And this is my Function definitions

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def webhomepage(request):
    return render(request,"HomePage.html")
def webpublicschoolspage(request):
    return render(request,"PublicSchools.html")
def webprivateschoolspage(request):
    return render(request,"PrivateSchools.html")
```

This is the structure of the code

[image]

Comment: Can you post your settings? We need some more info then this.

Comment: try this **from . import index**

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'HomePage.html',
    'PrivateSchools.html',
    'PublicSchools.html',

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'InstitutionFinderWebsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

Comment: Try `from InstitutionFinderWebsite import index` . Also I dont know why do you have the `htmlwesbsies` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. I suggest you the Basic Tutorial of Django here [Django Tutorial Part 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/) to get an overview how to structure your django project.

Comment: Please add extra information in the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: This was solved. Thanks